# Use of multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

i have an input like that:

```
City1 Neighbor1 Neighbor2 Neighbor3
City2 Neigbor1 Neighbor2
City3 Neighbor1 Neighbor2
City4 Neighbor1
```

I read the input by using for loop and trying to create a City Object where every City has its own neigbors.

```
public class City {
    String id;
    String name;
    ArrayList<String> connections=new ArrayList<>();

    public City(String id, String name, String ... a){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        for(String k : a){
            connections.add(k);
        }
    }   
}
```

I split the input and create a City object and add all of them into cities ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
cities.add(new City(splitted[0],connections));
```

Still it does not work. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks for help!

```
for(String list = b.readLine(); list != null; list = b.readLine()) {
    String[] splitted = list.split(" ");
    int l = splitted.length;
    connections = new String[l-1];
    for(int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++)
    {
        connections[i-1] = splitted[i];
    }
    cities.add(new City(splitted[1],connections));
}
```

Comment: post the splitting code as well....nothing wrong with this

Comment: for(String list = b.readLine(); list != null; list = b.readLine())
  {
   String[] splitted = list.split(" ");
   int c = splitted.length;
   connections = new String[c-1];
   for(int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++)
   {
    connections[i-1] = splitted[i];
   }
   cities.add(new City(parcala[1],connections));
  }

Comment: @MrE Edit it in, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Dont put code into comments; **always** update the question instead. Side note: if you have explicit classes that make up a "city"; then it is rather strange that your connections are strings. Meaning: you might want make a city object for each city first; and then you tell each city about its neighbor cities.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your City constructor and the way you actually create Cities - they don't match. You should create a City by calling `new City("some id", splitted[0], connections)`

Comment: Oh yes! How can i see the output of neighbors??

Comment: What do you mean by output o neighbors?

Comment: I want to see them by using System.out.println

Comment: If you have a `City c`, you can just call `System.out.println(c.connections)`, or use a loop; `for(String con : c.connections){ System.out.println(con); }`. And btw, please accept my answer if it was helpful.